# How can I reheat chicken without it getting rubbery or dry?

Tags: chicken, reheating

Reheating chicken in the microwave is usually a disaster, rubbery and awful or underheated.  In the toaster oven, the meat will frequently dry out.  How can I reheat it and keep the texture reasonable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try wrapping it in foil and cooking on a very low temperature in the oven or toaster oven. (Our oven has a "warm" setting that's ~170 F.) You can also include some water or broth in your foil packet but it won't penetrate much beyond the surface if the meat has been cooked before. It'll make that 1st bite taste more moist but in the long run it won't do much.

Comment: I disagree with not adding broth but otherwise I think reheating in foil packets in the oven is the best method. A little spoonful of broth in each packet with 2 or three slices of chicken is perfect (this also works well with turkey and roast gammon).

Answer (score 1):

Usually, when I want to reuse chicken from yesterday, I cut it and put it in a quiche.

Comment: There's a lot of things you can do to re-use chicken, where it's heating up in a moist environment (and if you cut it up,  you don't have the issues as significantly) ... ala king, pot pie, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I microwave it on defrost mode or, say, at 20% of full strength.  This also works for steak, pork, etc.  It takes longer than "hard nuking" it, but the wait is worth it.

Answer (score 0):

inject it with a syringe ( water , spices oil maybe) . reheat it

Answer (score 0):

You can just pull out a pan and heat the stove really quickly then fry it without oil, it'll get crispy and not chewy. It's really good and it works within three minutes.